# Task.Factory.StartNew isn't running how I expected

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, task

I've been trying to determine the best way of running code concurrently/in parallel with the rest of my code, probably using a thread. From what I've read, using `Thread` type is a no-no in modern C#. Initially I thought `Parallel.Invoke()`, but that turns out to be a blocking call till all the inner work is complete.

**In my application, I don't need to wait for anything to complete, I don't care about getting a result, I need code that is completely independent of the current thread. Basically a "fire and forget" idea.**

From what I thought I understand, `Task.Factory.StartNew()` is the correct way of running a piece of code concurrently/in parallel with the currently running code.

Based on that, I thought the following code would randomly print out "ABABBABABAA".

```
void Main()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("A");
        }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("B");
    }
}
```

However, it:

1. Prints out "BBBBBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAA"
2. If I swap the Task.Factory.StartNew with the `for` and vice-versa the same sequence is printed out, which seems bizarre.

So this leads me to think that `Task.Factory.StartNew()` is never actually scheduling work out to another thread, almost as if calling `StartNew` is a blocking call.

Given the requirement that I don't need to get any results or wait/`await`, would it be easier for me to simply create a new `Thread` and run my code there? The only problem that I have with this is that using a `Thread` seems to be the opposite of modern best practices and the book "Concurrency in C# 6.0" states:

> As soon as you type new Thread(), it’s over; your project already has legacy code

Comment: There is nothing odd with the output. The task "will run at some point after" it is scheduled. This time happens to be after the inline loop ran (as it was run immediately after the task was scheduled) and the test-code shows nothing interesting. Adding in a 100ms delays between each loop iteration in both cases should change the observation.

Comment: Hmm I see. I changed the loops to have a significantly higher value, now I'm seeing AAAAABBBBBAAAAA a lot. So was it the case that I was simply not giving enough time for the task to be scheduled?

Comment: In this case - yes. Also, most threads actually run interleaved and not truly concurrently (this is most trivial to visualize on a 1-core system; although an n-core processor will still run m threads where m >>> n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In my application, I don't need to wait for anything to complete, I don't care about getting a result, I need code that is completely independent of the current thread. Basically a "fire and forget" idea.

Are you sure? Fire-and-forget really means "I'm perfectly OK with exceptions being ignored." Since this is not what most people want, one common approach is to queue the work and save a `Task` representing that work, and join with it at the "end" of whatever your program does, just to make sure the not-quite-fire-and-forget work does complete successfully.

> I've been trying to determine the best way of running code concurrently/in parallel with the rest of my code, probably using a thread. From what I've read, using Thread type is a no-no in modern C#. Initially I thought Parallel.Invoke(), but that turns out to be a blocking call till all the inner work is complete.

True, parallel code will block the calling thread. This can be avoided by wrapping the parallel call in a `Task.Run` (illustrated by Recipe 7.4 in my book).

In your particular case (i.e., in a fire-and-forget scenario), you can just drop the `await` and have a bare `Task.Run`. Though as I mention above, it's probably better to just stash the `Task` away someplace and `await` it later.

> From what I thought I understand, Task.Factory.StartNew() is the correct way of running a piece of code concurrently/in parallel with the currently running code.

No, [`StartNew` is dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html) and should only be used as a last resort. The proper technique is `Task.Run`, and if you have truly *parallel* work to do (i.e., many chunks of CPU-bound code), then a `Task.Run` wrapper around `Parallel`/PLINQ would be best.

> Based on that, I thought the following code would randomly print out "ABABBABABAA".

As [others have noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42146461/263693), this is just a race condition. It takes time to queue work to the thread pool, and computers can count to 10 really fast. (Writing output is a lot slower, but it's still too fast here). The same problem would occur with `Task.Run` (or a manual `Thread`).

Answer (score 4):

Actually Task.Factory.StartNew does run on a seperate thread the only reason it loses the race everytime is because Task creation time. Here is code to prove it

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("A");
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("B");
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```